# Thunderbolt 3 PCI-E Cards

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-networking

I am planning to build a second system which will be used as in home (with some internet access) server. But mostly, it will be used to stream media over Plex.

Right now—on my main rig—I have about 6TB of TV series and movies, plus couple of music albums.

Initially, I thought that I would be able to get along with 1GPS links on my motherboards, however, transferring that amount of data will take roughly 12 hours, and, I want to use the new machine for web development and video editing, plus maybe as a Blender rendering “farm” later.

Buying new or even used 10Gbps PCI-E Cards + Switch is really expensive (at least where I live, which is probably 3 times more expensive than in US). And then it came to me that I might be able to utilize Thunderbolt 3 to achieve same 10Gbps (haven't seen any vendors claiming that it is possible to achieve 40Gbps) with a much lower amount of money invested.

Here are the specs of "current" and "new" machines (current / new):

1. **CPU**: i9-9900k / i7-8700k
2. **RAM**: 32GB / 16GB
3. **Motherboard**: MSI Z390 Ace / Asus Z370-E Gaming

And the first expansion card I found was from Asus, [Thunderbolt EX3](https://www.asus.com/Motherboard-Accessories/ThunderboltEX-3/), however, it states that it has some sort of "Thunderbolt Header", a bit unfortunate that both of the motherboards despite being more expensive than some of the "budget" ones, do not have this header, and motherboards 50-100$ cheaper do have it.

So now I am lost: Do I really need this header for this expansion card to work, or "beefier" motherboards do not need this header?

Also, what about other vendors, most of them have no such thing as dedicated Thunderbolt header.

Do you have any good suggestions about possible choices when it comes to buying Thunderbolt 3 expansion cards for PC-to-PC LAN connection?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if the 10 GBE connection is only necessary for the initial transfer, I'd suggest taking out the harddrives and putting both a source and a destination harddrive into the same machine for copying. That's the fastest way you can copy disks, the limit will be write speed. For NAS (network attached storage) with a semi-professional use-case (Blender), I'd consider investing in a ready-made NAS (e.g. Synology), instead of trying to build your own system.

Comment: The problem is, that the cheapest Synology is around 1000 USD here (trully, the CHEAPEST), and i just so happen to have CPU, Mobo and GPU. I am also going to use this server for Web Dev, so was looking for more of a "server" rather than NAS approach.

Comment: (Please edit your question with additional information like the one you gave in the comment; comments may not stick around). So if I understand you correctly, you need hardware recommendations for fast LAN (which doesn't really fit this particular stack exchange) for one (which one?) or both of the motherboards you already have? And I'd still separate the bandwidth requirements for the "copy all disks once" use case from the "do normal work" use case (web development doesn't need 10 GBE).

Comment: Also, consider that your LAN card has to attach to something. Looking at the specs of the MSI Z390 Ace, you have 3x PCI-E X1 and 3x PCI-E X16 (unless I missed something), so the only way to attach a fast LAN card is in one PCE-E X16 slot, and AFAIK that won't give you 10 GBE.